# Angular Search Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I was wondering why the Angular Search box does not work, when I load it up locally in my computer. I am using the same code and it does work when I use sites like codepen, plunker, or jsfiddle. What am I doing wrong that it is not working properly?

```css
.example-animate-container {
  background:white;
  border:5px solid red;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.animate-repeat {
  line-height:40px;
  list-style:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
.animate-repeat.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
  max-height:0;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
.animate-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  max-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example89-production</title>
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  <div ng-init="buildings = [
  {name:'Carver-Hawkeye Arena', location:'1 Elliott Drive Iowa City, IA', facility:'athletics', initials:'CHA'},
  {name:'Ronald McDonald House', location:'730 Hawkins Drive Iowa City, IA', facility:'athletics', initials:'RMCD'},
  {name:'Substation U Control Building ', location:'755 Hawkins Dr.Iowa City, IA', facility:'athletics', initials:'SUBU'},
  {name:'Duane Banks Baseball Stadium', location:'960 Stadium Dr Iowa City, IA', facility:'athletics', initials:'BASE'},
  {name:'Football Operations Facility', location:'992 Evashevski Drive Iowa City, IA 52242', facility:'athletics', initials:'FOF'},
  {name:'Kinnick Stadium and Press Box', location:'825 Stadium Dr Iowa City, IA ', facility:'athletics', initials:'KS'},
  {name:'Recreation Building', location:'930 Evashevski Dr Iowa City, IA ', facility:'athletics', initials:'RB'},
  {name:'West Campus Transportation Center', location:'840 Evashevski Drive Iowa City, IA 52242', facility:'athletics', initials:'WCTC'},
  {name:'Altgeld Hall', location:'608 South Wright Street, Urbana, IL 61801', facility:'athletics', initials:'hall'},
  {name:'Center for Disabilities and Development', location:'330 Hawkins Drive Iowa City, Iowa 52242',facility:'UIHC', initials:'CDD'},
  {name:'Hospital Parking Ramp 3 ', location:'800 Evashevski Drive Iowa City, IA',facility:'UIHC', initials:'HPR3'},
  {name:'Hospital Parking Ramp 1', location:'230 Hawkins Drive Iowa City, IA 52242',facility:'UIHC', initials:'HPR1'},
  {name:'Boyd Tower', location:'601 Newton Road Iowa City, Iowa 52242',facility:'UIHC', initials:'BT'},
  {name:'General Hospital', location:'220 Hawkins Drive Iowa City, Iowa 52242',facility:'UIHC', initials:'GH'},
  {name:'South Wing', location:'210 Hawkins Drive Iowa City, Iowa 52242',facility:'UIHC', initials:'SW'},
  {name:'Medical Research Facility ', location:'55 South Grand Avenue Iowa City, Iowa 52242',facility:'UIHC', initials:'MRF'},
  {name:'Shipping and Receiving', location:'65 South Grand Avenue Iowa City, Iowa 52242',facility:'UIHC', initials:'SAR'},
  {name:'Dental Science Building', location:'801 Newton Rd Iowa City, IA',facility:'Health Sciences', initials:'DSB'},
  {name:'Chilled Water Plant 2 ', location:'305 Hawkins Drive Iowa City, IA ',facility:'Health Sciences', initials:'CWP'},
  {name:'Wendell Johnson Speech & Hearing Center', location:'250 Hawkins Dr Iowa City, IA',facility:'Health Sciences', initials:'SHC'},
  {name:'Hardin Library for Health Sciences ', location:'600 Newton Rd. Iowa City, IA',facility:'Health Sciences', initials:'HLHS'},
  {name:'Medical Education Building', location:'500 Newton Rd Iowa City, IA',facility:'Health Sciences', initials:'MEB'},
  {name:'Newton Road Parking Ramp ', location:'360 Newton Rd. Iowa City, IA',facility:'Health Sciences', initials:'NRP'},
  {name:'Quadrangle Residence Hall', location:'310 South Grand Ave Iowa City, IA',facility:'West Residences', initials:'Q'},
  {name:'Hillcrest Residence Hall', location:'25 Byington Rd. Iowa City, IA',facility:'West Residences', initials:'H'},
  {name:'Rienow Residence Hall ', location:'320 Grand Ave. Iowa City, IA',facility:'West Residences', initials:'R'},
  {name:'Slater Residence Hall', location:'325 Grand Ave. Iowa City, IA',facility:'West Residences', initials:'S'},
  {name:'Field House', location:'225 South Grand Ave Iowa City, IA',facility:'Near West Campus', initials:'FH'},
  {name:'South Quadrangle', location:'310 South Grand Ave. Iowa City, IA',facility:'Near West Campus', initials:'SQ'},
  {name:'Gerdin Athletic Learning Center', location:'402 Melrose Avenue Iowa City, IA',facility:'Near West Campus', initials:'GALC'},
  {name:'Boyd Law Building', location:'130 Byington Rd. Iowa City, IA',facility:'Near West Campus', initials:'BLB'},
  {name:'Stanley Hydraulics Laboratory', location:'320 South Riverside Dr Iowa City, IA',facility:'Near West Campus', initials:'SHL'},
  {name:'Asian Pacific American Cultural Center', location:'223 Lucon Drive Iowa City, IA',facility:'Near West Campus', initials:'APAC'},
  {name:'Offsite Building 1', location:'223 Lucon Drive Iowa City, IA',facility:'offsite', initials:'OS1'},
  {name:'Offsite Building 2', location:'223 Lucon Drive Iowa City, IA',facility:'offsite', initials:'OS2'},
  {name:'Offsite Building 3', location:'223 Lucon Drive Iowa City, IA',facility:'offsite', initials:'OS3'}

]">

  You have {{buildings.length}} buildings. Search:
  <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter buildings..." />
  <ul class="example-animate-container">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="building in buildings | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] <strong>Building:</strong>{{building.name}} <strong>Location:</strong> {{building.location}}.
    </li>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length == 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length == 555">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works for me in this demo

Comment: Did you check for javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the way you include the JavaScript libraries from the CDN:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Adding `http://` should do the trick.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your script source doesn't use a protocol in the URL so when it is opened on your local machine it is looking at **file://ajax.googleapis.com...** which doesn't exist.

Using a protocol of **http** or **https** on your local machine will fix the issue.